# installing composer failes. Unable to access http://

Tags: ubuntu, installation, curl

I am trying to install composer with the command:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

And I am getting this error:

```
PHP Warning:  Directive 'safe_mode' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
#!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:

Your PHP (5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18) is quite old, upgrading to PHP 5.3.4 or higher is recommended.
Composer works with 5.3.2+ for most people, but there might be edge case issues.

Downloading...
Download failed: Unable to access https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
Downloading...
Download failed: Unable to access https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
Downloading...
Download failed: Unable to access https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: disabling safe_mode did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it on mine:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:

Your PHP (5.3.3) is quite old, upgrading to PHP 5.3.4 or higher is recommended.
Composer works with 5.3.2+ for most people, but there might be edge case issues.

Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /home/alexus/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jun 27 2012 14:13:03) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

Try to updating your PHP package first and give it a go again.

seems like some php extensisons are missing on your end, here is what I have installed on my end:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ rpm -qa | grep ^php
php-mysql-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
php-pear-1.9.4-4.el6.noarch
php-pecl-xhprof-0.9.2-5.el6.x86_64
php-gd-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
php-pear-Console-Color-1.0.3-1.el6.noarch
php-mbstring-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
php-pdo-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
php-common-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
php-soap-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
phpMyAdmin-3.5.4-1.el6.noarch
php-php-gettext-1.0.11-3.el6.noarch
php-xml-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64
php-pear-Console-Table-1.1.4-1.el6.2.noarch
php-mcrypt-5.3.3-1.el6.x86_64
php-cli-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
php-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

Comment: I did an update/upgrade -> still same

Comment: I'm looking at code, it seems like something from your PHP is missing and it's not missing in mine, can you look at developer's site see if they have requirements for PHP as well (try to install them).

Comment: As far as I can see (http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-json-project-setup), there are no further requirements... any other idea?

Comment: check my list, see what's missing...

Comment: Up for you help. Couldnt solf it so I updated my VM from 9.* to 10.* and tada: working. (Yes, I know this not the best way to do it)

Comment: @Jan1337z actually, maybe it is)) please mark my answer as right))